# How can I make color retain its properties behind glass?

Tags: node-editor, properties, glass

Every time I apply a glass sphere around my eye, to give it the circular texture and glossiness, it creates a couple problems. The iris color changes as I put the eyeball into the glass sphere. I've tried tweaking the settings to make it more clear. The best I can do is in the material viewport, it shows the true color. But the rendered it doesn't show the true color, instead its a darker shade. I've included the pictures to show what I mean, and the node of the glass eye. The only modifiers affect the two objects are a mirror modifier that is irrelevant to the transparency properties. I've also allowed refraction and screen space reflections from the properties tab. Anything would be helpful, even if its a explanation of whether I'm doing this right or wrong (I'm just lost and confused, I don't even know if I'm doing this right.)

In the first image its viewport is in render, and the second is in material viewport. After that, I put the nodes of the glass.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Edit1: It's not based off the light source either, I've shined a 1000 watt light source at the eye, and it still gives off the shade.

Comment: please specify if you are using eevee or cycles.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using eevee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your node setup is not the ideal way to do glass in EEVEE (I assume that's what you're using). For proper glass, use this setup (note the highlighted Blend Modes)

[image: GlassEye]

Comment: Ah, thank you! This works way better than setting transmission to 1 and calling it. Thanks!